# ALERT ! UUID- does not exist. Dropping to a shell

Tags: boot, raid, fstab, uuid

I have got problem in Ubuntu 16.04.

My system has 2 drives with RAID 1. I tried all that I found but didn't work.  I matched the `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file with both `/dev/md126` also with `UUID-....` but it didn't work.

My system shows this error message on boot:

```
(cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT ! UUID-853f6ofa-be83-4b2c-b111-89f7fb09d20ff does not exist. Dropping to a shell
```

Below is the out for blkid

```
/dev/sdc1: UUID="2016-04-20-22-45-29-00" LABEL="Ubuntu-Server 16.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="4cbe268b" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="4cbe268b-01"
/dev/sdc2: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="B1F5-0A13" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="4cbe268b-02"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="b1e8f589-8e85-4396-f038-bda09701b1e4" UUID_SUB="70870fef-1666-c0e2-e80d-719c290f2b10" LABEL="Odoo:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="2c3f2dea-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="8cd06e11-af74-a75b-e1f6-228eed6e6e50" UUID_SUB="c9afe7eb-e625-be77-64c1-f13e79fb0eb0" LABEL="odoo:128" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="2c3f2dea-02"
/dev/sda1: UUID="b1e8f589-8e85-4396-f038-bda09701b1e4" UUID_SUB="eb4b677b-7d08-eaed-bcee-afe4853de434" LABEL="Odoo:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="ed1431b2-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="8cd06e11-af74-a75b-e1f6-228eed6e6e50" UUID_SUB="8ca1a95f-7651-b741-7c03-8d217b1be0f9" LABEL="odoo:128" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="ed1431b2-02"
/dev/md127: UUID="853f60fa-be83-4b2c-b111-89f7b09d20ff" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/md126: UUID="ce1bb201-a6ee-402b-9aa3-e782560575d9" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="GRMCULFRER_" UUID="4823-0029" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="fdc01076-01"
```

`/etc/fstab` contents:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/md128 during installation
UUID=853f60fa-be83-4b2c-b111-89f7b09d20ff /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/md127 during installation
UUID=ce1bb201-a6ee-402b-9aa3-e782560575d9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you update your question by doing a copy-paste of those output to a file? E.g. connect a USB key, mount it and do `blkid > /media/sdb1/blkid_out.txt`. It would be much easier for other people to find your question.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I have paste the output. Please check.

Comment: Good. Please also include `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto /etc/fstab included

Comment: I fixed the formatting again. :) Please consider using proper formatting, especially with code blocks: it helps to read the question. See this [post on meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/) as well. Regarding your problem, firstly try the solution proposed in the possible duplicate (especially the `update-initramfs -u` part).

Comment: I did as the post. Got below result after I run update-grub."WARNING: Failed to connect lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning. grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdc1. Check your device.map. done" @AndreaLazzarotto